# Unity 2D Physics: angle limits and motors are preventing rigidbodies to sleep

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, box2d, game-physics, unity3d-2dtools

**Aim:** I'm developing a turn-based game that heavily relies on Unity's 2D physics. It's important for me that all bodies go to sleep as soon as they stop moving, because I'm waiting for it to start next turn.

**Issue:** Unfortunately, it happens quite often that bodies *never* go to sleep. I tried tweaking Physics2D settings for days, thus improving stability and/or performances, but this issue still occurred. I figured out that this problem is related to HingeJoint2Ds: when they try to enforce a constraint (both *angle limits* or *motor force*), they won't allow their connected bodies to sleep.

I also tried to manually set really slow moving bodies to sleep, but (and this sounds quite weird to me) it seems that calling *.Sleep()* on a body causes other bodies to wake up, thus preventing the whole world to ever be able to fall asleep.

**Question:** Is anybody facing a similar situation? Any clue or workaround on how to solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: Make sure the rigid bodies are not colliding or receiving force. As this will force them to wake up. You might want to keep applying the sleep as well, as the sleep Forces a rigidbody to sleep at least one frame. But not necessary several.

Comment: Hi MX D,
thanks for your advice.

I'm sure no forces are being applied: the only things that keep bodies awake are some angle limits and/or motors (with 0 speed).. as soon as I disable them, entire world fall asleep.

For now, I'm using a workaround that constantly checks each rigidbody and if it doesn't find any velocity (or angularVelocity) above sleep tolerance, it forces entire scene to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried grouping them under a sleeping parent game object then removing the ones you want to be awake from this object?

Comment: I don't think I get your point.
GameObject hierarchy does not affect Rigidbody2D and physics calculations, afaik. Also, I don't want any object to stay awake, I only want them to sleep when they are below linear/angular velocity thresholds, despite having unsatisfied angle limits.